Tiktok Authorization / Authorization Error
For authorization, I am using "https://auth.tiktok-shops.com/oauth/authorize" API. I have connected my first shop using these api. For the new shop when i trying to connect using these API it's shows the old shop in the authenticate popup. how can we manage multiple shop ?
